# tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: called twice in a row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

because I'm adding an object to one instance of an array, but then reloading the table view from another instance of what is supposed to be the same array. How can I create a single instance of the array and just pass it around from class to class? I can do it easily in java, but in Objective-C you can't make static variables so I'm not sure how to do this.

EDIT: more code.
Here is a method from another class that is called in order to save a file. I'm using Core Data, so first it adds the file to the context (model), then to the array, then it saves the context. This method is in a class called 'Player'

```
-(BOOL)saveRecording {
    Bank *B = [MusikerViewController daBank];
    AudioTableViewController *ATVC2 = [MusikerViewController ATVControl];
    NSLog(@"Place A");
   AudioFile *myAudioFileMusicX314 = [[B addAudioFileEntityToModelWithDate:myDate andURLString:strPath] retain];
    NSLog(@"Place B");

    myAudioFileMusicX314.type = true;

    [ATVC2 addAudioEntityToArray:myAudioFileMusicX314];
    NSLog(@"Place C ***********************************************");

    if(![B saveContext]) { //save context after adding file to keep consistancy
        NSLog(@"addAudioFileEntityToModel is returning a nil managedObjectContext");
        return NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"Place D");

    [myDate release];
    [strPath release];
    [myAudioFileMusicX314 release];
    [ATVC2 release];
    NSLog(@"Place E");

    return YES;

}
```

The following method is in the class that contains the table view--its caled AudioTableViewController

```
    -(void)addAudioEntityToArray:(AudioFile *)event {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    if(event.type) {
        [[MusikerViewController recordingsArray] addObject:event];//self?
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }

    else {
        [[MusikerViewController downloadsArray] addObject:event];
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    }

    [[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:NO];
   [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

The following method adds the object to my model

```
- (AudioFile *)addAudioFileEntityToModelWithDate:(NSDate *)theD andURLString:(NSString *)str {
    NSLog(@"addAudio...WithDate -- called");
    sound = (AudioFile *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AudioFile" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    sound.creationDate = theD;
    sound.soundPath = str; //set the sound path to the sound file's url
    [self alertForTitle];

    NSLog(@"No problems yet at place D - addaudio...String, sound title is %@", sound.title);
    NSLog(@"Context at addAudioFileEntityToModel is: %@", managedObjectContext);

    return sound;
}
```

here is the important parts of MusikViewController.h -- it keeps track of recordingsArray and downloadsArray

```
@interface MusikerViewController : UIViewController {
}

NSMutableArray   *recordingsArray;
NSMutableArray   *downloadsArray;

+ (NSMutableArray *)recordingsArray;
+ (NSMutableArray *)downloadsArray;
```

and MusikViewController.m

```
 + (NSMutableArray *)recordingsArray {
    NSLog(@"recordingsArray called");

    if(!recordingsArray) {
        recordingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *bigTempArray = [[[[Bank alloc] init] autorelease] getFetchArray]; //change this
        for(AudioFile *af in bigTempArray)
            if(af.type) {
                [recordingsArray addObject:af];
            }
        NSLog(@"recordingsArray exists");
    }
    return recordingsArray;
}

+ (NSMutableArray *)downloadsArray {
    NSLog(@"recordingsArray called");

    if(!downloadsArray) {
        downloadsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // if(!bigTempArray)
        NSMutableArray *bigTempArray = [[[[Bank alloc] init] autorelease] getFetchArray];
        for(AudioFile *af in bigTempArray)
            if(!af.type) {
                [downloadsArray addObject:af];
            }
    }
    return downloadsArray;
}
```

and some AudioTableViewController methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"Place F");    

    if(section == 0) {
    return [[MusikerViewController recordingsArray] count];
    }
    else if (section == 1) {
        return [[MusikerViewController downloadsArray] count];
    }

}

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        AudioFile *event;
        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        event = (AudioFile *)[[MusikerViewController recordingsArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            NSLog(@"downAry indexPath caled at cellForRow...Path");
            event = (AudioFile *)[[MusikerViewController downloadsArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        if(event.title) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [Player dateString:event.creationDate];
        cell.textLabel.text = event.title;
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = [Player dateString:event.creationDate];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        }

        return cell;
    }


            - (void)viewDidLoad //viewDidLoad for AudioTableViewController
            {
                [[self tableView] reloadData];
                NSLog(@"viewDidLoad called for AudioTableViewController");

                [super viewDidLoad];

                self.title = @"Audio Files";//put this in application delegate

                // Set up the buttons.
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
            }
```

Comment: Are you inserting rows, e.g.: via insertRowsAtIndexPaths, but not updating the result returned from numberOfRowsInSection?  ie: you report there are 9 items, then insert a new row, then still report only 9 items (instead of 10)?

Comment: provide the code of all table view delegate methods.And row insertion code if any

Comment: Your code logs "Place F" *and* "Place I" for each call of numberOfRowsInSection, so it is not consistent with the shown output. Please post your actual code.

Comment: how is it not consistent? this is my actual code

Comment: @NicholasHart actually it updates correctly (so there are 8 things, I add 1, now there are 9), but then numberOfRowsInSection calls itself again and reports that there were 9 things (last time it was called), 1 was added, but there are still only 9 things.

Answer (score 0):

If your data model changes you need to either reload the tableView, or insert/remove the rows otherwise the tableview will freak out on you.  It doesn't matter how many times tableView:numberOfRowsInSection is called, your data model can't return a different number without first reloading or updating the tableview.

Based on your logging my guess is that your downloads array is changing quantities.  It makes it past the NSLog then dies in _endCellAnimationsWithContext.

Comment: I've called [[self tableView] reloadData] in my viewDidLoad method and  [[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:NO];
   [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]                   withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; In the method I use to add things to the table view

Comment: Im sure ur right anout there being an incosistancy with my array somewhere, at least that would make the most sense. But ive spent a week going through my code and trying new things and rewriting entier classes and ive gotten almost no where. I have no idea where the inconsitency could possibly b... It is very very frusterating :p

Comment: this method is wrong: (void)addAudioEntityToArray:(AudioFile *)event

should look like this:
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesnt seem to have any effect. At least not one i can see from the console or the UI